# What should I do when the correct answer changes

Tags: discussion

Almost 2 years ago I asked this Q:
[AngularJS : transcluding multiple sub elements in a single Angular directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079587/angularjs-transcluding-multiple-sub-elements-in-a-single-angular-directive/34063645#34063645)

I received an answer (the one by hassassin) which was correct at the time and I up-voated and accepted it.

Now a short time ago, kevinius provided a new answer which Is a better.
However, its important to say that this new answer could not have been provided in the past - The circumstances have changed, and the library I asked about has added a feature that does what I asked for.

IMHO, For anyone that would come now looking for an answer to the same problem I wrote about - the new answer would be more appropriate and helpful.

I obviously up-voted the answer provided by kevinius.
But should I remove the up-vote i previously gave hassassin and what about the accepted answer? should I Should I change my accepted answer?

I don't want hassassin to loose any reputation just because his answer is no longer the best possible answer, but I do think that people that would come today to look at this Q should pay attention to the answer provided by kevinius.

Or Maybe I should add an update to the Q pointing people to the answer provided by kevinius?

Comment: Side note: it may be good time to edit your question and remove "new here"/"searched a lot"/"thank you" text...

Comment: "too bad that they did not update the docs".  Ugh.  Have you verified yourself that the new answer is in fact a good solution to your original problem?  Then you can change the accepted answer.  @hassassin got plenty of votes for his original answer and he rarely shows up, losing 15 rep is not the end of the world.  A DV is a bit excessive perhaps.

Comment: 1) My Q is not just about selecting between two correct answers. I am talking about a specific case when the correctness/relevance of the Q has changed over time. And the original answer was well written and did help at the time.

Comment: 2) As for the side note - I think it is important to give the appropriate background when asking a Q. Its used to explain both my knowledge level of that topic at the time and that I am not asking instead of trying to find an answer on my own but rather that I tried and could not.
As for my "Thank you" - I find it to be polite and looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  i do not see any guidelines advising against it - is there any good reason to avoid this?

Comment: 3) The answers In the duplicate reference Q (and the duplicate reference Q of that one) both seem to say that I should change the accepted answer but leave the upvotes in place. and it does sound reasonable. Piskvor suggested just that below and got down voated with no comment - I am confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly why the "accepted answer" checkmark is not set in stone: so that it can be changed in case a new answer now gives a better solution.

In other words: do not remove your upvote, just accept a different answer.

Comment: could the person that down voted this answer please explain why he did so?

Comment: I'd say it meant "you stupid Piskvor, there's already a better answer for this, don't add duplicates" ;o) I should have searched, that's indeed a frequently-asked question.

Comment: The fact is that I have searched and did not feel that I found a Q that asks the same Q ans I had. Because of the significant time between the two given answers and the fact that they where both "The best" answer for when they where given. Its not just about selecting between two different answers.  looking at "When should I vote up/down?" n http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down and http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up I don't see any justification for why your answer should be down voted - at least not in relation to my Q's beeing a duplicate.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer (and up-vote it). it might be a good idea to also state that if the accepted answer would change than it would attract enough attention and will eventually get more up-votes then the old answer.
Thanks, You have been helpfull.